# How to lay-out a list of links so the intended reading order is apparent?

Tags: website-design, page-layout, information-architecture

I have a site (no CMS platform) that has a list with links. The list consists of 14 links, each referring to a `pdf` file. If someone wants to
read the content of these files, they must follow a certain path. For example,
to be able to understand what the 7th link/pdf says, they have to have read the 1st, then the 3rd and then go to the 7th. The same goes for the other links, too.

My problem is how to present the list so as to instruct the reader in the path they have to follow, and how to present this in a nice and clear way? A clear way to present and for them to navigate through the files?

jquery, diagram software with images instead of text, anything you have to propose.

thank you

Comment: Can't you merge those pdf's into one multi page pdf?

Comment: What if you made an icon for each (numbers would work fine, icons are prettier though), and in parenthesis after each list item, you had a comma separated list of icons representing the required reading? ie, after the title for your 7th item, you'd have the icons for 1 and 3 in parenthesis, etc.

Comment: I flagged your post as doesn't belong here - I think you should get a Mod to move this to the User Interface (UX) exchange.

Comment: @Lollero that would be a good choice but i have to keep them seperate

Comment: @Heroes182 i thought of icons also. i'll try to find a way to that direction.

Comment: @Ryan sorry ryna i am new. i didn't know there is ux exchange. what is a Mod?

Comment: Mod = Moderator, someone that can actually move this

Comment: Welcome to GraphicDesign.SE.  Can you edit your question to be more clear?  As it stands, I'm not sure if you are looking for presentation of a list outside of documents, or presentation of the list within documents, or presentation without the list inside documents; and whether you want software, or technique, or another alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one simple solution. Try putting the links in sections with headings, like so:

### Heading 1

1. Link 1
2. Link 3
3. Link 7

### Heading 2

1. Link 2
2. Link 4
3. Link 5

Etc.

Make each heading a descriptive name that describes the overall content of following that path.